# width of the html page (body ) not extending while resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css

when I decrease the browser window size and scroll horizontally, I get white space to the right, the width of the HTML is not extending to full screen, I tried with many  methods none of them working,

I tried `min-width`, `max-width`, using `vw` but none worked

```
  html,
  body,
  #app,
  .container-fluid {
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   display: table;
   }

  html {
   background-color: red;
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO1RU.png)

Comment: Provide your full HTML and CSS code or jsfiddle

Comment: Try with min-width:100%

Comment: Please provide all needed code (preferably in a snippet) to reproduce your problem. So also include your html.

Comment: You didn't reset the margins to 0.

Comment: You have to provide us with more of your code if you want help as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Need to reset default browser css use:

```
  *{
   margin:0;
  }
```

Comment: i have added this but didnt work .the width of the page is not extending after  1568px *768px resolution

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
*{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```